# Tfs - Report on work items with history comments

Tags: reporting-services

I am working with Tfs2012 trying to create a tabular report (either excel or reporting services) that contains amongst other things (id,lifecycle,title,assigned to,..), the comments users manually entered in the History field.

I did find references on how to do this using the Tfs API but that is just too cumbersome to deploy and also would require extra coding to format a report in some form, things that are easily done using SSRS.

Any pointers to how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Certain fields (the ones that are marked Reportable) are automatically transported to the TFS Warehouse tables. This includes all history for these reportable fields. If you want to display fields that are not reportable then the officially supported route is through the TFS Client Object Model.

There is a trick you can employ to expose the information gathered from the Client Object Model through an OData feed or a Soap webservice. You can then bind that to a SQL Server Report. The [Visual Studio ALM Rangers Reporting Guide](http://vsarreportguide.codeplex.com/) explains how to do this.

The following package:

> [image: icon] [TFS Practical Reporting Guide Data Warehouse Package](http://vsarreportguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/115743)
>
> <sup>example, 74K, uploaded Dec 5</sup>

Contains an example which shows the Build Queue information by exposing a webservice to Report Server. the data for the report is retrieved through the TFS Client Object Model.

The approach is described in the second ebook that accompanies the same guidance package.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I am a bit reluctant to have to set up an extra server/service. I'd rather stick with a vanilla tfs installation. But if all else fails, I guess I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

As you might know, TFS uses MSSQL database to store all the data. In your situation I would go to querying TFS database directly.

It will take some time to make all the queries you need, but after that you will be able to use them directly in MSSQL Reporting Services or even Excel.

This should get you going:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/10/23/tfs2010-sql-queries-for-tfs-statistics.aspx
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/03/09/inside-the-tfs-databases-an-occasional-series.aspx

Comment: This is completely unsupported and the Database Schema can and will change between TFS versions. It is highly *not* recommended.

Comment: It depends on what OP wants to do with this report. If it is some kind of internal report that will be run only on TFS2012, I guess it is OK because it gets your job done. If it is for some commercial usage, I would stick to TFS API.

Comment: Why the downvote? Maybe this is not the most practical solution for large reports but with small reports it would help to get job done in no time. If you take a look at links I posted you would see that even guys from Microsoft uses this approach time by time by themselves.

Comment: The important difference is that when Microsoft writes these they're considered somewhat supported. When you go about the TFS databases on your own behalf you void support for the environment. Both articles clearly give the warning. Yes you can do it, but if there are alternatives, they're often better. The OP's request can easily be implemented using the Client Object Model, as such there is no need for direct SQL access. Plus, TFS2012 has received 4 update packs, some of which changed the schema, just not a good idea!

Comment: I need a "stupid" excel like table , containing roughly : "Id,Title,Assigned To, History". Where history is reversed chronological list of "manually" entered comments in the history field. Seems trivial enough to me not having to go through either extra services or not support table queries ....apparently it is not :(

Comment: Won't a well defined Web Access Query deliver you equal value?